# How can I test a function which returns an element on Jest/Enzyme?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs, enzyme

So the Jest logs says line 64 needs coverage.

I have this on my code:

(it is a datatable component where you are able to expand its rows to see more content).

```
{row.isExpanded && (
    <TableExpandedRow>
      <TableCell colSpan={headers.length + 1} key={row.id}>
        <div className="wrapper wrapper-items-table">
          <div className="table">
            <TableItemsHeader />
            {tableRows.map(
              items =>
                isEqual(items.id.toString(), row.id) && ( // LINE 64
                  <TableExpandedRowWrapper
                    key={items}
                    rowClassProp="row"
                    shipmentItem={items}
                  />
                ),
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </TableCell>
    </TableExpandedRow>
  )}
```

That `isEqual()` method you saw above is from lodash.

And I have this on my test:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      t: k => k,
      tableRows: [
        {
          id: '123',
          shipmentId: '- -',
        },
      ],
      headers: [
        {
          key: 'shipmentId',
          header: 'Shipment ID',
        },
      ],
    };
  });

  it('renders ShipmentsTable component', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<TableComp.WrappedComponent {...props} />);


    // I know this is not doing anything but
    // this is the part I need to test
    const row = { id: '123' };
    const rows = props.tableRows.map(
      items =>
        isEqual(items.id.toString(), row.id) && (
          <TableExpandedRowWrapper
            key={items}
            rowClassProp="row"
            shipmentItem={items}
          />
        ),
    );

    expect(wrapper.find(DataTable)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
```

So do you have any ideas on how can I test that chunk of code?

Comment: so whatever `row` is in your component you need it to have `id` the same as one of `tableRows` item you are passing. and next you will check `expect(wrapper.find(TableExpandedRowWrapper)).toHaveLength(1);`

Comment: @skyboyer it gives length 0 so it throws an error.

Comment: extract it to separate component, and it would be much easier to test ( as well as catch bug if test fail in future).

Comment: That is an extracted component where I am calling it there as a child component.